# $_GET can't receive data from url

Tags: php, get

My code is:

```
<?php 
print_r($_GET);   

<div id="admin_details">
    <?php 
    $user =new User();
    $all_admin=$user->find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM admin");
    ?>
    <table>
      <tr><th>User name</th><th>Rule</th><th>Last login</th><th>Action</th></tr>
      <?php
       foreach ($all_admin as $admin) {
          echo "<tr><td>".$admin->user_name."</td>"."<td>".$admin->rule."</td>".
          "<td>".$admin->login."</td>"."<td>".
          '<a class="del" href="#?id=' .$admin->admin_id .'&op=del "> Delete</a>'.

          '<a class="edit" href="#?id='.$admin->admin_id .'&op=edit "> Edit </a>'.
          '<a class="view" href="#?id='.$admin->admin_id . '&op=view "> view </a>'.
          '<a class="block" href="#?id='.$admin->admin_id .'&op=block ">block</a>'.
          "</td></tr>" ;
        } 
        if(empty($all_admin))
        {
          echo '<tr><td colspan="4">'.'<div class="error_msg">No admin found </div>'.'</td></tr>';
        }
      ?>

    </table>
    </div>
?>
```

print_r($_GET); should show id and op value in url when I click edit,view or block link. But it is showing  'Array ( )' Whats problem going on in my code?

Comment: Show us the entire url you are working with including the query string

Comment: `print_r()` is doing what it should. Try using `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: Using the hash (#) refers to an anchor within the page, thus no request is sent to the server when you click any of the links.

Comment: You will $_GET in the form of an array. So there is nothing wrong in it. What you should be worried about is that it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the hash `#` symbol. When you click on a link, a new page is not loaded (the browser will look for an ID on the page) so nothing is appended to the url.

You should change your links to:

```
'<a class="del" href="?id=' .$admin->admin_id .'&op=del "> Delete</a>'
                     ^ here
```

etc.

If you want to stay on the same page when you click one of the links, you would need ajax.